# How to get the cumulative sum of different linearized line plots when they are overlapped

Tags: python, pandas, math, plot

So I have the following pandas dataframe

Start time | End time | Value|
0;50;50
20;100;800
10;45;700
which each row represents a line in plot from start time til end time linearized (time are x axis)

the result dataframe should have
x | value
0;0
10;10
20;220
45;995
50; 1050;
100; 1550

each value correspond a point in the graphic and are connected by a line plot

e.g: start time: 0 End time: 5, there will be a linearized line from 0 til 5.

The problem is that when there are two rows that are having overlaps of time. For the overlapping part I want to get the cumulative sum of the fraction of each row. (and this should be applied to the rest of the lines too)

How could I achieve this? I tried to sort by start time but have no clue how to continue.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQ0uf.png)

I will draw a graphic to better illustrate what I want to achieve

So as you can see, each circle in the second graph corresponds the sum of the fraction of the lines that are overlapped

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Could you create (in code) a set of test data (e.g. 3 rows)? And the corresponding plot?  How should "Value" be interpreted? Is that linearly increasing from 0 at the Start and the given value at the End (the current example doesn't contain a 'Value')?

Comment: yes, gonna add it

Answer (score 0):

This may not be scalable depending on the size of your `DataFrame`.

Some data to get us started.

```
import pandas as pd
from plotnine import *

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'StartTime':(0,20,10),
    'EndTime':(50,100,45),
    'Value':(50,800,700)
})
```

First, create a `DataFrame` of x-coordinates for all the inflection points.

```
xyCoordinates = df['StartTime']
xyCoordinates = xyCoordinates.append(df['EndTime']).sort_values()
xyCoordinates = xyCoordinates.reset_index(drop=True)
xyCoordinates = xyCoordinates.to_frame('x')
xyCoordinates['y'] = 0
```

[image]

Then iterate over each of the rows in `df` and iterate over each of the inflection points in `xyCoordinates`, and for each x-coordinate in `xyCoordinates` calculate the y-coordinate based on the slope of the line. Iteratively add this value to the y-coordinate in `xyCoordinates`.  Because in your example the value when x=50 is given as 1050 rather than 350, I am assuming that once a line ends, it stays at its maximum value and contributes to the cumulative total rather than disappears to 0.

```
for df_index, df_row in df.iterrows():
    for xy_index, xy_row in xyCoordinates.iterrows():
        if (xy_row['x'] >= df_row['StartTime']):
            y = ( df_row['Value'] / (df_row['EndTime']-df_row['StartTime']) ) * ( min(xy_row['x'],df_row['EndTime'])-df_row['StartTime'])
            xy_row['y'] += y
```

This produces:

[image]

Can we can plot as:

```
p = (ggplot(xyCoordinates, aes(x='x',y='y'))
  + geom_line()
)
p
```

[image]